# Ubuntu 10.04: Unable to Start RabbitMQ Server Post-Installation

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, rabbitmq

After installing RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 10.04 I receive a failure message that the service was unable to start. Any insight into the issue would be greatly appreciated! Below are contents of startup_log and startup_err.

Startup_log:

```
{error_logger,{{2012,7,7},{15,50,31}},"Protocol: ~p: register error: ~p~n",["inet_tcp",{{badmatch,{error,etimedout}},[{inet_tcp_dist,listen,1},{net_kernel,start_protos,4},{net_kernel,start_protos,3},{net_kernel,init_node,2},{net_kernel,init,1},{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,7,7},{15,50,31}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.20.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.9.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[#Port<0.100>,<0.17.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,false}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,24},{reductions,512}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2012,7,7},{15,50,31}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfa,{net_kernel,start_link,[[rabbitmqprelaunch877,shortnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,7,7},{15,50,31}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,shutdown},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfa,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,7,7},{15,50,31}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
```

Startup_err:

```
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

Comment: How did you install RabbitMQ? Did you use the old obsolete one from the Ubuntu distro? Or did you download the latest one from http://www.rabbitmq.com/ with lots of bugfixes, speed improvements and much improved clustering?

Answer (score 0):

I can't definitively pinpoint the error, but in general you can read the stack in the first error_logger line -- inet_tcp_dist (tcp distribution) tried to bind to listen but got `{error,etimedout}`

This then generated a `badmatch` as it wasn't expected -- this is a normal Erlang idiom. It looks like it couldn't find epmd.

More specifically, [this post from 2010](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2010-March/006586.html) looks exactly like your problem - try the easy answer of making sure that RabbitMQ isn't already running, otherwise [ensure you have a loopback interface and there's no firewall on it](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=498068).